# Fn+8 not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, fn-key

Lenovo T420 running Windows 7 64-bit.  Fn+8 key combo is not working to let me access Ultranav settings.  Control Panel > Mouse also does not have a tab for UltraNav, only settings for a normal mouse (though its cursor movement speed control works with the Ultranav).  By the way Fn+F6 and Fn+F3 also don't work, though other Fn combos do work (Brightness, overhead light).  I'm most concerned with getting at the UltraNav settings though.

Comment: do you have the ultranav drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you dont have the proper driver/application that supports the Lenovo specific function keys.  You would need to download them from the Lenovo website.  I took a quick look and it appears that model is no longer in production.  I assume you recently upgraded to Win 7 and thats when this issue started.  If there are no Win 7 drivers, you can try drivers for older OS, they may work.